# EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal

Tags: python, string, eof

i've looked on the web and here but i didn't find an answer :
here is my code

```
zlib.decompress("""
xﾜﾭﾔ=ﾗﾲHﾅs~Ʀﾽç\ﾑîà
Z@ÑÁÔQÇlxÇÆïPP~ýVãìﾞM6ÛÐ|ê֭ﾢﾤﾔ=)}éÓUe﬿ö3ﾺﾸú"}ʿïÿ÷1þ8ñ́U÷ﾻñíLÒVi:`ﾳﾺL!Ê҆p6-%Fë^ﾍ÷à,Q.K!ﾕô`ÄA!ÑêweÌ ÊÚAﾛYøøÂjôóﾠÂcñ䊧fﾮùﾃúN :nüzAÝ7%ﾸcdUﾀﾸ3ôPۂﾀlﾝyHﾬﾽ$/yzﾾíàﾇ'ÕÓ&`|S!<'ﾤ÷Zļﾼ2ﾎﾓ;ﾆ(ÅÛfb!úü$ﾅﾃﾾ,9ßhàPﾺﾨێﾌÑbØὛﾎQﾹ-Ü}(n;ﾨﾎLﾔ\^ï9ﾦﾹﾗDdВéÞ|åPOGﾤÐÙ%â&AÔë)ÎTÐC ﾼïc枢í%Èï!ﾌﾷëiq*ﾸVKÐNﾴ[ﾢfOq{OﾦÆÊ,0GﾤﾘmtﾂﾳOﾸΥ$#îﾍqbYﾱﾒUﾆﾵÞáP`
ﾖ×ﾯÃPwaﾚǩâ×)ﾊFcêÚ=!Åöﾶ
)AFñﾳ/cMﾧ!NóNΈór?pàÜòXw
Bvæ0ïçIÉoﾏ>5pﾦ-ØWÚNﾱùFﾱØPçÃþdﾠ;ﾙ1[Oﾳﾎ~6ﾂﾳﾥŕìﾨޠ=øð@ﾈV﾿ﾩ)÷%ﾕÜib{HﾱKŅVlDCﾃîfÑWì÷ìáár.ﾜîv﾿<dﾺn~ú*ÁÕ7ýá}EsYﾯWﾤÈ:R×ãQңﾒ?Ø1vﾍäﾂ~èR1ﾵÜ*ﾴónAﾥjmNoﾂﾕﾳÌښﾥf[8ﾦÛ>ﾞOWﾗ|ÌbDﾢÖ녡M=Ð÷èâﾐﾑ'ÂÝÐ ;ë mﾺQÂäԤۢ:ﾓﾱdﾺﾽLȂ1ﾳ_÷YZﾬNòÛ â\ﾛxÐlݵﾯﾑﾫøm5Ëá=ïoÍlMﾣ[×#Ypﾠﾄx[ÉÊyæﾂoﾓﾅz)ﾦﾡÝÏìò
""")
```

so it was a string that i got by zlib.compress an other string.
How can i decompress this string ?
Regards
Bussiere

Comment: This question presents a compelling case for a "WTF?" tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zlib.decompress should work if you pass it the output of zlib.compress.

Since the compressed string is really not text it is a binary string.  It will not play friendly with displaying to the terminal as you have found.

You can use base64 encoding to give you something safe to drop into unittests, paste into code etc.

```
>>> import zlib
>>> a = zlib.compress('fooo')
>>> b = a.encode('base64')
>>> b
'eJxLy8/PBwAENgG0\n'
>>> c = 'eJxLy8/PBwAENgG0\n'.decode('base64')
>>> zlib.decompress(c)
'fooo'
>>> zlib.decompress(a)
'fooo'
```

**a** as an output is ok for binary transmission or saving to a file.

**b** is friendly to use with the clipboard, send in email, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would not have it in that representation. Use `repr()` in the other code to generate an ASCII-clean representation, and use that instead. Then just look for triple quotes in the result and break them up.

Comment: I will use also the base64 repr but your answer helped me thanks and regards.